# How to assemble HTML documents with Webpack?

Tags: html, webpack

Is there a way to piece meal your HTML too with Webpack so you have HTML chunks instead of large HTML files?

Example:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>Here is the main page </div>
        <script>
        // inject a chunk of HTML here
            require.include('./header.html');
        </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

I saw the HTML loader but I don't think I can use it for this purpose.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you need this [html-loader](https://github.com/webpack/html-loader)

Edited:

You can use interpolate flag to enable interpolation syntax for ES6 template strings, like so:

```
require("html?interpolate!./file.html");

<img src="${require(`./images/gallery.png`)}" />
<div>${require('./partials/gallery.html')}</div>
```